# How do I make a listbox clickable, and redirect to a new page in a Windows Phone project?

Tags: windows-phone-7, button, listbox

I have a Listbox in my Windows Phone page, that contains some text among other things. I want each grouped item to be clickable and taken to the same destination page, but passing a different parameter each time. This is the closest approximation to what I want right now:

```
        <ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" Name="MainListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Width="460" Height="220" ClickMode="Release" Click="Button_Click" Tag="{Binding Name1}" BorderThickness="0" >
                        <Button.Content>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17" >
                                <Border Background="#FFE5001b" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,9,0"  >
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name2, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-28,9,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" FontSize="40" Name="Name2" />
                                </Border>
                                <StackPanel Width="311">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name1, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontStretch="Condensed" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name3, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name4, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Calories, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

The problem is that the click is set to Release (if set to Press, I cannot scroll at all). Everytime I try to scroll up/down, I get the momentary white glow associated with the click of a button. How do I do this correctly? I don't mind not using the button, just want this to work :/

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx) out.
In the selection changed event handler you can decide which page to navigate based on which item was selected.
And no need for the button inside the template.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a button for this.

Look at the code generated when you create a new DataBound application. It will show a way of doing what you are trying to achieve.